# How can I make a UICollectionView animate inside a collection view cell like App Store?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How can I achieve something like below:

[image]
The collection view is moving gently inside the collection view cell even when I'm scrolling through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I does create simple project with desire animation, i didn't implement exact same position of elements as in AppStore, but i just show you basic animation and how to implement it. Also i didn't check when `collectionView` reach the end and i just populate it with 100 elements.

> I does add `GIF` it's frame rate is low, on simulator it's looks fine, **no laggs**.

[image]

`AnimatedCollectionViewController.swift` class

```
class AnimatedCollectionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private let identifier = String(describing: AnimatedCollectionViewCell.self)
    private var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /// Loading custom `nib`
        let nib = UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: Bundle.main)
        collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        /// Starting animation
        startAutoScrollCardsCollectionView()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        /// Remove timer from `RunLoop` object
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil // just in case
    }

    private func startAutoScrollCardsCollectionView() {

        /// This method start timer and fire it immediately
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [unowned self] _ in
            let currentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset
            self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: currentOffset.x + 5, y: currentOffset.y), animated: true)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource extension

extension AnimatedCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout extension

extension AnimatedCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Dummy `AnimatedCollectionViewCell.swift` class

```
class AnimatedCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:   .random(),
                       green: .random(),
                       blue:  .random(),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

---

So what basically is happening, is I start a `Timer` and fire it's immediately. And this timer calls `completion` 0.1 sec and inside this completion i change `setContentOffset.x` position of `collectionView`.

You can go from here and add custom layout to cell's position and also check when `collectionView` reach end.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `CollectionKit` framework 
https://github.com/SoySauceLab/CollectionKit

```
// apply to the entire CollectionView
collectionView.animator = ScaleAnimator()

// apply to a single section, will override CollectionView's animator
provider.animator = FadeAnimator()

// apply to a single view, will take priority over all other animators
view.collectionAnimator = WobbleAnimator()
```

you can also apply some other best animations in collection view 
https://github.com/onmyway133/fantastic-ios-animation/blob/master/Animation/layout.md

Answer (score 0):

This one belong to the cell in CollectionView. You can animate your UIImageView in cell manually by calling

```
class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, 
    animations: @escaping () -> Void)
```

You can find more information on Apple document or stackoverflow.